# Iterative subtraction of elements in array in Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, iteration, subtraction

I have a large numpy array. Is there a way to subtract each element with the elements below it, and store the result in a new list/array, without using a loop.

A simple example of what I mean:

```
a = numpy.array([4,3,2,1])

result = [4-3, 4-2, 4-1, 3-2, 3-1, 2-1] = [1, 2, 3, 1, 2 ,1]
```

Note that the 'real' array I am working with doesn't contain numbers in sequence. This is just to make the example simple.

I know the result should have (n-1)! elements, where n is the size of the array.

Is there a way to do this without using a loop, but by repeating the array in a 'smart' way?

Thanks!

Comment: Why (n-1)! elements? It looks to me like it should be n choose 2.

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely right! it is nC2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a [`masking`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.indexing.html#boolean-or-mask-index-arrays) based approach for the extraction after broadcasted subtractions and for the mask creation we are again making use of `broadcasting` (double `broadcasting` powered so to speak) -

```
r = np.arange(a.size)
out = (a[:, None] - a)[r[:,None] < r]
```

**Runtime test**

Vectorized approaches -

```
# @user2357112's solution
def pairwise_diff_triu_indices_based(a):
    return (a[:, None] - a)[np.triu_indices(len(a), k=1)]

# Proposed in this post
def pairwise_diff_masking_based(a):
    r = np.arange(a.size)
    return (a[:, None] - a)[r[:,None] < r]
```

Timings -

```
In [109]: a = np.arange(2000)

In [110]: %timeit pairwise_diff_triu_indices_based(a)
10 loops, best of 3: 36.1 ms per loop

In [111]: %timeit pairwise_diff_masking_based(a)
100 loops, best of 3: 11.8 ms per loop
```

**Closer look at involved performance parameters**

Let's dig deep a bit through the timings on this setup to study how much mask based approach helps. Now, for comparison there are two parts - Mask creation vs. indices creation and Mask based boolean indexing vs. integer based indexing.

**How much mask creation helps?**

```
In [37]: r = np.arange(a.size)

In [38]: %timeit np.arange(a.size)
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.88 µs per loop

In [39]: %timeit r[:,None] < r
100 loops, best of 3: 3 ms per loop

In [40]: %timeit np.triu_indices(len(a), k=1)
100 loops, best of 3: 14.7 ms per loop
```

About `5x` improvement on mask creation over index setup.

**How much boolean indexing helps against integer based indexing?**

```
In [41]: mask = r[:,None] < r

In [42]: idx = np.triu_indices(len(a), k=1)

In [43]: subs = a[:, None] - a

In [44]: %timeit subs[mask]
100 loops, best of 3: 4.15 ms per loop

In [45]: %timeit subs[idx]
100 loops, best of 3: 10.9 ms per loop
```

About `2.5x` improvement here.

Comment: That's a much faster way to extract the upper triangle.

Comment: @user2357112 Yup! Added a bit of closer look on it.

Answer (score 3):

```
temp = a[:, None] - a
result = temp[np.triu_indices(len(a), k=1)]
```

Perform all pairwise subtractions to produce `temp`, including subtracting elements from themselves and subtracting earlier elements from later elements, then use `triu_indices` to select the results we want. ([`a[:, None]` adds an extra length-1 axis to `a`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#numpy.newaxis).)

Note that almost all of the runtime is spent constructing `result` from `temp` (because `triu_indices` is slow and using indices to select the upper triangle of an array is slow). If you can use `temp` directly, you can save a lot of time:

```
In [13]: a = numpy.arange(2000)

In [14]: %%timeit
   ....: temp = a[:, None] - a
   ....: 
100 loops, best of 3: 6.99 ms per loop

In [15]: %%timeit
   ....: temp = a[:, None] - a
   ....: result = temp[numpy.triu_indices(len(a), k=1)]
   ....: 
10 loops, best of 3: 51.7 ms per loop
```

Comment: Elegant ! Can you give a reference for this `a[:,None]` indexing you are using.

Comment: @SomeGuy: Added.

Answer (score 1):

```
a = [4, 3, 2, 1]
differences = ((x - y) for i, x in enumerate(a) for y in a[i+1:])
for diff in differences:
  # do something with difference.
  pass
```

Comment: yes, but list comprehension uses loops! My array is too large!

Comment: In NumPy, "without using a loop" includes list comprehensions and other constructs that perform iteration in Python. The goal is to get all the iteration into C loops over unboxed data.

Comment: Is there a way to do this by repeating the array in a smart way so that in the end all you need to do is subtract 1 array from another?

Comment: Well, I changed it to a generator comprehension which ought to handle enormous lists. You can iterate over that and pull results one at a time. This is definitely how I'd write it, but I'm no numpy expert.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [`itertools.combinations`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations):

```
from itertools import combinations

l = [4, 3, 2, 1]

result = []
for n1, n2 in combinations(l, 2):
    result.append(n1 - n2)

print result
```

Results in:

```
[1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1]
```

`combinations` returns a generator, so this is good for very large lists :)